# ORC format - PIG - dependent libraries

Tags: apache-pig, orc

I understand to write into ORC format + snappy compression (pig script),

using OrcStorage('-c SNAPPY')

I need your help, what is the SET command or necessary library I need to include to enable storing result dataset into ORC format?

Please help.

Subra

Answer (score 2):

Check what pig version are you using.
ORC storage is available from pig14 as a build in function. 
Check the examples:
https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/func.html#OrcStorage

UPDATE

This pig just works fine:

```
data = LOAD 'SO/date.txt' USING PigStorage(' ') AS (ts:chararray);
STORE data INTO 'orc/snappy' using OrcStorage('-c SNAPPY');
data_orc = LOAD 'orc/snappy' using OrcStorage('-c SNAPPY');
DUMP data_orc;
```

You don't even need to register the kryo jar, because that not used directly from the pig so it will be optimized out, but you use it via reflection so you have to  add the kryo jar to the classpath, like this:

```
pig -latest -useHCatalog  -cp ./kryo-2.24.0.jar orc.pig
```

Comment: pig script failed to validate: java.lang.RuntimeException: could not instantiate 'OrcStorage' with arguments '[-c Snappy]'

Comment: I am getting the following error,  pig script failed to validate: java.lang.RuntimeException: could not instantiate 'OrcStorage' with arguments '[-c Snappy]'  I have used SET mapred.output.compression.codec org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec.  What else I am missing.  I am using pig 0.15 version.

Comment: I changed Snappy to SNAPPY. Now, I am getting, ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser - ERROR 2997: Unable to recreate exception from backed error: Error: org/iq80/snappy/Snappy.  My final statement is, STORE OmniGen into '/demo/output4' using OrcStorage('-c SNAPPY');

Comment: Based on the OrcStorage.java source
(http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pig/trunk/src/org/apache/pig/builtin/OrcStorage.java?view=markup) -c, --compress Sets the generic compression that is used to compress the data.
Valid codecs are: NONE, ZLIB, SNAPPY, LZO
Tomorrow I'll try it to you

Comment: May some lib is missing for the snappy codec. I'm not sure if piggybank has it or hadoop-snappy needed. I'll test it